Can't add more than 1 tract in react native track player
I am developing a music player app with React Native Expo & to play music using the library react-native-track-player
I am having issues with adding more than 1 track
if I add just a single track with this code working fine
await TrackPlayer.add([selectedTrack])

but when try to add multiple tracks(array of tracks), getting issue
code
 await TrackPlayer.add(tracks)

error 
[Error: url: The URL cannot be empty]

even I try
await TrackPlayer.setQueue(tracks)

but same error
getting data with REST API &  checked there is mp3 URL at evey url key
I tried to much but didn't figure out issue
package json
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"expo": "~51.0.28",
"expo-router": "~3.5.23",
"react-native-track-player": "^4.1.1",

Thanks in advance for help
